# Adding fifth join in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have so far written the following mysql query which is joining 4 tables as follows:

```
SELECT 
T3.fault, t4.name
FROM table2 T2 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND a.submit_id < b.submit_id
    WHERE b.submit_id IS NULL
) T1  ON T1.item_id = T2.item_id
INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T1.id = T3.run_id
LEFT JOIN table4 T4
ON 3.runname_id  = T4.id
order by count(*) desc;
```

Below is sample Data for `table 2` which has `item_id` as `PK`
Example query: `select * from table2 where item_id = '15907';`

```
item_id  host
15907    abc.com
7303     cde.com
7304     abcd.com
7305     cdedf.com
```

I have now recently added a table `table5` which looks as below and has `item_id` as `PK`. I want to join `table5` with `table2` on `item_id` and want to retrieve value for `restoreid` also in my final query.

```
item_id  restoreId
15907       12342
7303        12342
7304        14342
7305        14342
```

How to implement join between `table5` and `table2` on `item_id`? My select query should also retrieve `T5.restoreId` along with `T3.fault, t4.name`

Comment: You are not joining T3 with T4 correctly. You have missed (T). Try the answer I have provided

Answer (score 1):

```
select your_table.fault,your_table.name,t5.restoreid
from (
    SELECT 
    T3.fault, t4.name,t2.item_id
    FROM table2 T2 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT a.*
        FROM table1 a
        LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND a.submit_id < b.submit_id
        WHERE b.submit_id IS NULL
    ) T1  ON T1.item_id = T2.item_id
    INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T1.id = T3.run_id
    LEFT JOIN table4 T4
    ON 3.runname_id  = T4.id
) as your_table left join table5 t5 on your_table.item_id = t5.item_id
```

Comment: I am getting error `syntax error unexpected your_table`

Comment: Sorry, try now.

Comment: Yeah, men. Try it now

Comment: Hi, thanks for the query. I don't want `item_id` to be shown in the final output. Is there way to omit that?

Comment: Yes, i modified query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
T3.fault, t4.name, T5.restoreid
FROM table2 T2 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.item_id = b.item_id AND a.submit_id < b.submit_id
    WHERE b.submit_id IS NULL
) T1  ON T1.item_id = T2.item_id
INNER JOIN table3 T3 ON T1.id = T3.run_id
LEFT JOIN table4 T4
ON T3.runname_id  = T4.id
LEFT JOIN table5 ON T2.item_id = T5.item_id;
```